# Xamarin forms phone call is not working on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, phone-call

I have the following code, I'm trying to make a phone call. It is working on Android but not iOS!!

```
  private void Call_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var phoneDialer = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;
        //if (phoneDialer.CanMakePhoneCall)
        //    phoneDialer.MakePhoneCall("+9611578268");
        Device.OpenUri(new Uri("tel:738284739"));
    }
```

I tried both commented and uncommented code, both didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try this on a real device? This is not implemented in the Simulator

Comment: I tried it on a real device for the Android and it works fine!

Comment: And did you try it on a real device for iOS?

Comment: I think I need to place the app on the App Store to be able to test it on a real device. And I can't do that at the moment

Comment: You should be able to debug it on a real device, also for iOS without going to the store. In any case, what I mean is: the "open phone app" isn't available on the iOS Simulator because Apple didn't implement it. That is why it doesn't _seem_ to work. On a real device I am pretty confident it will work

Comment: @mohammad anouti There is no need for you place the app on the App Store to test it. You can test it when your are debugging and it's free. You can refer to :[Xamarin.iOS App Distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/).  Again, phone call will not work on a iOS Simulator, you need to test in a real device.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Dependency Services on native level because preformation will be high and easy to mange the native API. Please check the below Implementation it will help you.

Create the interface in your PCL Project-

```
 public interface ICall
 {
   bool OpenCallAction(string phoneNumber);
 }
```

Create class in your IOS Native Project-

```
public class ICallService : ICall
{
    public bool OpenCallAction(string phoneNumber)
    {
        var number = new Uri(String.Format("tel:{0}", phoneNumber));
        return UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(number);
    }
 }
```

Create class in your Android  Native Project-

```
public class ICallService : ICall
{

    public bool OpenCallAction(string phoneNumber)
    {
        var number = new Uri(String.Format("tel:{0}", phoneNumber));
        return true;
    }
```

Call Dependency Service ViewModel/View in PCL project

```
 DependencyService.Get<ICall>().OpenCallAction("738284739")
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object occurred, On Calling the OpenCallAction it gives my null reference exception

Comment: Can you please paste the code where you are getting the exception ? How to Implementation dependency service please check here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: Yes, @DineshPhalwadiya is right missed the code thanks

Comment: Welcome @Pratius